# What is the closest word meaning "respect for time / mindful"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a one (or two word if necessary) expression that describes the character trait of mindfulness and a desire to stay focused on completing a purpose in a period of time.  This implies the quality that one is not easily distracted but doesn't have to imply competence or effectiveness.

**The context**

> I'm describing the core values of our company, so this word will be
>   listed along other words such as "Authenticity", "Curiousity", etc.

**Here's some words that don't quite work**

- **Punctual** is only a partial hit, because I'm not necessarily talking about "showing up" for the starting and stopping of a task.  **EDIT** - This word also implies a cold indifference where I'm trying to imply a respect for the limits time
- **Focused** also only covers part of what I'm looking for, but doesn't
  cover the intention to complete a task within a window.
- **Effective** is somewhat implied, but not quite it either as I want to isolate the intention and ability to deliver the requirements on time without speaking to the quality of the work (at least for this word)

Comment: *Punctual* does not just mean showing up for a task. It also means completing a task on time. (Although, perhaps you would still object because something could be done punctually *by accident* rather than with intention.)

Comment: I could live with "punctual" as close enough except that I feel it implies a kind of cold indifference that could send the wrong message.

Comment: "Diligent" has at least some of the connotations you're looking for, and is a positive description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**conscientious(ness)**

It’s not clear if you want a noun (like "curiosity") or an adjective (like "punctual"), but the difference is easily addressed.

From Collins via [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Conscientious):

> Conscientious (adj)
>
> 1. involving or taking great care; painstaking; diligent

It implies that care is taken in everything, especially task/time management.

Comment: Task/time management aren't in the definition anywhere, but I think I get what you mean as I think common use of conscientious tends to include thinking about time.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend

***purposeful***.

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purposeful) :

1: having a purpose:

such as

a: MEANINGFUL

// purposeful activities

b: INTENTIONAL

// purposeful ambiguity

2: full of determination

// was soft-spoken but purposeful

Comment: This is very close and I almost picked it.  I'm way into splitting hairs here, but purposeful doesn't make me think of schedules as much as I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I like cognizant.
having knowledge or being aware of.
"statesmen must be cognizant of the political boundaries within which they work"

Comment: Welcome to English.SE. --- It's always useful to [include some references](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/what-to-reference-when-answering-a-question) (see also the first link) and explain why (or have it be obvious once the references are consulted) your answer is particularly good. This will improve the number of upvotes you receive because you've offered a better answer. While it's great that you provided an example of the usage notice the difference between your answer and the others.

Answer (score 0):

Clock work.  Maybe clock work monster if one wants to exaggerate. It was once used in a novel( I forgot it's name).  It implies that one is very predictable.  But in that novel it was used to describe someone who did not waste time in fun activities and is very punctual.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of the adjective [**tenacious**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tenacious)? The noun form of this word would be [**tenacity**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tenacity). This word basically means *being persistent in achieving your goals*. This sounds like something that closely fits your description. The Collins English Dictionary gives it the following definition:

> If you are tenacious, you are very determined and do not give up easily.

Example sentence:

> She is very **tenacious** and will work hard and long to achieve objectives.

Another good word you might consider is [**diligence**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/diligence) (**diligent** would be the adjective form):

> Careful and persistent work or effort